# Load balancing ACIs inside a Vnet

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-container-instances

I have Azure Container Instances inside a vnet and I want to implement load balancing but cannot think of a workable solution. For context, it will be a set of VMs contacting the load balancing resource which would direct the request to one of the ACIs.

Things I have tried thus far are Azure Load Balancer (does not work with ACI) and Azure Traffic Manager (cannot be inside a vnet). I don't think an application gateway is a feasible solution either. I want to know if anyone has faced this scenario before and how did they overcome it or if someone has a potential solution that I can test out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, to access the ACI inside a VNet through a Load Balancer, you just need to create a Load Balancer and add the backend pool with the IP address of the ACI, here is a screenshot for it:

[image]

Then create a health probe and load balancer rule for the port you need. When all things are OK, you can access the ACI inside the VNet through the Public IP address:

Result:

[image]

ACI:

[image]

Load Balancer:

[image]